# Looping fails to produce an output to the console for subset code

Tags: r, subset

`POI[[1]]` returns a list of shortest paths. But it also has another 44 list members that each return a list of shortest paths. Here is an example.

```
 > POI[[1]]
[[1]]
+ 1/44 vertex, named:
[1] V1

[[2]]
+ 2/44 vertices, named:
[1] V1 V2

[[3]]
+ 2/44 vertices, named:
[1] V1 V3

[[4]]
+ 2/44 vertices, named:
[1] V1  V3A

[[5]]
+ 2/44 vertices, named:
[1] V1 V4
```

...and so on, 39 more times.

Now, this piece of code returns all of vectors that contain a specific vector sequence. The vector sequence is held in `chain`.

```
chain <- c(1,3)

POI[[1]][sapply(POI[[1]], function(x) any(
      intersect( which( x==chain[1]), # check for first value
                 # then see if any of those locations also have successive differences are the same as in the `sample` item.
                 which( diff(x) == diff(chain) ))  ))]
```

However, when I try iterating this function over every list member, it doesn't output anything to console (not even an error).

Here is the generalized for loop code.

```
for(i in 44){ POI[[i]][sapply(POI[[i]], function(x) any(
      intersect( which( x==chain[1]), # check for first value
                 # then see if any of those locations also have successive differences are the same as in the `sample` item.
                 which( diff(x) == diff(chain) ))  ))] }
```

Does anybody know why this might be the case?

Comment: 1. code in a for loop will never produce output to the screen unless you explicitly print it (for instance, try `for (i in 1:100) { i + 1 }`- this won't print anything unless you do `for (i in 1:100) { print(i + 1) }`). So put a `print` statement around it. 2. You probably mean `for (i in 1:44)` rather than `for (i in 44)`- the latter will happen only once.

Comment: Thank you, it works beautifully. And indeed, that is what I mean. @DavidRobinson

Answer (score 0):

1. code in a for loop will never produce output to the screen unless you explicitly print it (for instance, try for (i in 1:100) { i + 1 }- this won't print anything unless you do for (i in 1:100) { print(i + 1) }). So put a print statement around it. 2. You probably mean for (i in 1:44) rather than for (i in 44)- the latter will happen only once. – @DavidRobinson